# rewrite query sign in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url with query in the midle of request uri ex:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?/recipe_category/recipe/
```

I've trying to remove the `index.php` as well but it leave the query sign (?) so the url become

```
http://domain.com/?/recipe_category/recipe/
```

How to remove all of the [index.php?]? For your information, my htaccess written as below :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I use framework codeigniter how to write **RewriteRule \??\/?. index.php** completely in htaccess??

Answer (score 0):

You can use following lines to remove "index.php?"

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php\?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]